# Cannot extend nor lock Azure immutability policy from command line: Operation not allowed on immutability policy with incorrect etag

Tags: azure, immutability, azure-cli, etag

I am using [Azure immutable storage, aka WORM (Write Once, Read Many)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/immutable-storage-overview).

I am trying to set the immutability policies using the `az` command line, [as documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/immutable-policy-configure-container-scope). I can *create* policies from the CLI, but that's all. I cannot extend locked policies, nor can I lock unlocked ones.

Example (using PowerShell in Windows):

```
$etag = az storage container immutability-policy show `
    --account-name <a-name> `
    --container-name <c-name> `
    --query etag `
    --output tsv
# This yields a sane-looking ETag, a 15-digit hexadecimal string.
az storage container immutability-policy lock `
    --account-name <a-name> `
    --container-name <c-name> `
    --if-match $etag
```

This gives an error message:

> (ContainerImmutabilityPolicyFailure) Operation not allowed on immutability policy with incorrect etag.
> Code: ContainerImmutabilityPolicyFailure
> Message: Operation not allowed on immutability policy with incorrect etag.

I get the same error message if I send `--if-match *`.

If I omit `--if-match` entirely it throws an error.

If I try to look up the policy by ETag I can find the policy fine:

```
az storage container immutability-policy show `
  --account-name <a-name> `
  --container-name <c-name> `
  --if-match $etag
```

Adding `--resource-group <r-name>` makes no difference.

I can lock and extend these policies fine from the Azure portal (browser GUI), logged in with the same credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my login was set to the wrong subscription, and the error message is just bad. I think I fixed it by doing this:

```
az account set --subscription <name-of-subscription-where-storage-account-is>
```

Comment: I have the same error, but resetting the subscription didn't work. I even tried `az logout` and logging in again. Locking the policy in the UI works, only the azure cli command doesn't work. Very odd.